# Entity Framework Core creating model from existing Oracle database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to create the models in entity framework core from existing oracle database ,
I installed the required packages for oracle database which is :

```
Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (to use Scaffold-DbContext command)
```

Then when I used the following command to create the tables from database to Models folder I got this error :

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=trng;Password=fhir;Data Source=caredb:1521/care;" 

-Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UseOracle 

-OutputDir Models 

-Context FHIRDBContext 

-Tables APPT_CLINICS 
 
   Build started...
 
   Build succeeded.
 
   Unable to find provider assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UseOracle'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project.
```

what is the correct provider for Oracle database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching and trying I found the solution change the provider from this :

```
-Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UseOracle
```

To this code :

```
-Provider Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
```

And this is the complete command

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=trng;Password=fhir;Data Source=caredb:1521/care;" 

-Provider Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore

-OutputDir Models 

-Context FHIRDBContext 

-Tables APPT_CLINICS
```

UPDATE :

Till now Package

`Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore`

is not compatible with netcoreapp 3.1 last version 6.2 install last stable version < 6 for example 5.2

Comment: Err: 
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=IMART_SYSTEM;Password=69nu4Yk2099vl4wv6L41M2uX3i2D0B;Data Source=10.34.0.59:1521/tmiorcl;" -Provider Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -Context OracleDBContext -Tables FMS_FC_JRNL_DTL 
Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Scaffold-DbContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException